# Visual Studio Cannot Create new ASP.NET Web Application - No IIS Express folder in Documents

Tags: iis-express

When loading in a solution that uses IIS express, or trying to create a new ASP.NET Web Application I receive errors.

When loading an existing solution I get "Creation of the virtual directory failed with the error: Unable to access the IIS metabase. You do not have sufficient privilege to access IIS web sites on your machine"

When creating a new project I get "Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL))"

Following these responses: 
[Visual Studio 2013: Unable to access IIS metabase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36478858/visual-studio-2013-unable-to-access-iis-metabase) and
[Error - Unable to access the IIS metabase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859891/error-unable-to-access-the-iis-metabase/17460774#17460774)

So far I have:
- Uninstalled/Reinstalled IIS
- Repaired, and uninstalled reinstalled Visual Studio
- Ran VS as admin
- Repaired IIS
- Changed the registry key in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders\Common Documents the value was set to P:\ updated to C:\Users\user\Documents
- Reinstalled .NET Framework and .NET Core

I have found that there is no IIS Express folder in Documents, even after reinstalling and I think this may be the cause of the issue - does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio? 2013? Via Control Panel | Program can you see IIS Express installed?

Comment: Using Visual Studio 2017, in Progams and Features, IIS Express 10.0 is listed and gives me the option to uninstall.