# Creation of the virtual directory failed. Unable to access the IIS metabase

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2013, iis-metabase

http://puu.sh/8TK3x.png

This is the issue I face, one of the projects in my solution sits on 'load failed' after a fresh windows install and attempted fetching of the solution from team foundation server.

So far I have:

Attempted to navigate to a few folders to see if it prompts for a permission override - no success

Taken ownership of the IIS config folders and enabled editing.

Attempted to set the UseIIS to false and changed the ports in the csproj file.

Any other things I should try?

Using VS 2013

Comment: Could not resolve, reinstalled OS as it was wasting my time.

Comment: this helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273044/visual-studio-cant-create-web-site-in-iis
Changed Default app pool to ASP.NET v4.0

Comment: Uninstalling IIS, rebooting and then reinstalling IIS worked for me (In `Turn windows features on or off` for Windows 7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No resolution, had to reinstall OS.